# some error of Wordpress with my IE

Tags: wordpress

When I use Chrome and Firefox with this website http://hyojung.vn/network and it's work perfectly, but I move to IE all of my products is showed in 1 column as some small divices. How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide folks with more info.

What version of IE are we talking about.

From a quick look, you are using flexbox which is not fully supported below IE11.

Comment: I'm using IE 8 :)

Comment: but this is Wordpress, how can it be?

Comment: Has nothing to do with Wordpress. It's the Themes CSS/JS